# getClientOriginalName() on string when it is an object?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I keep getting the error message

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string
```

The `test.mp4` file exists and is on my localhost. The part I don't understand is that `$file` is not a string?

```
$file = File::get(storage_path('app/uploads/test.mp4'));

$original_name = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Any help would be appreciated explaining what I am doing wrong.

edit:
after reading the PHP docs I realized that `file_get_contents` returns a string. So my question is: How do I make on object out of `storage_path('app/uploads/test.mp4')` so I can get the original name of a file?

Comment: so the File::get() function returns a string... how does that function looks like?

Comment: it is a wrapper for PHP's file_get_contents.

Comment: and file_get_contents gets the content of a file and places it into a string. You better explain us what you want to make...

Comment: you're right, my bad. I just checked the PHP docs

Comment: not. you can get the original filename at the moment that the file has been uploaded. On that moment you will  have to store that name e.g. into the database or it will be lost for ever (unless you move the uploaded file to the original name of course which has serious backdraws)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense then. I thought I was missing something. I would accept that as the correct answer if I could.